# How do I eager load on creation of new objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am creating suggestions in my app as usual:

```
class SuggestionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @suggestion = current_user.suggestions.new(params[:suggestion])

    if @suggestion.save
      render :show, status: :created
    else
      render :error, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

Each suggestion belongs to a service (the `service_id` is sent to the create action in the `params[:suggestion]`).

When I return the suggestion to the client, I would like to include the details of the suggestion's service in the JSON. This means that I should eager load it somewhere to save on database requests.

This would be fine if I was finding the suggestion:

```
Suggestion.includes(:service).find(params[:id])
```

Can I do something similar on saving?

```
@suggestion = current_user.suggestions.new(params[:suggestion])
# This doesn't work.
@suggestion.includes(:service).save
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this as part of default scope in your suggestion model

```
scope :includes(:service)
```

Comment: I'd like a way to do it on a once off basis if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't eager load on a save. Only on a query. However, once you save and you return @suggestion to the view accessing @suggestion.service will hit the database and return the appropriate data for you.